# Как узнать, какое изображение загружено?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Есть такая конструкция:

```html
<picture>
  <source srcset="mdn-logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
  <img src="mdn-logo.png" alt="MDN">
</picture>
```

Как узнать, с помощью JS, какая из картинок активна?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что в вашем случае поможет свойство [`currentSrc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/currentSrc) :

```js
let oImg = document.querySelector('img');
oImg.onload = function() { console.log( this.currentSrc ); }
oImg.onerror = function() { console.log( 'Изображение недоступно.' ); }
```

```html
<picture>
  <source srcset="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Badge.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
  <img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Badge_512.png" alt="MDN">
</picture>
```